# linq Any operator with not equal(!=)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I'm having trouble understanding the linq any operator. Lets consider the following snippet of code (using VS 2010 and .Net 4.0)

```
List<string> sample = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
List<string> secondSample = new List<string> {  "b", "c" };

foreach (string s in sample)
{
    if(secondSample.Any(data=> data.ToString() == s))
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

When run it produces the following output

```
b
c
```

Which is what I'm expecting. However if I change the equality operator(`==`) to Not Equal(`!=`) I get this

```
a
b
c
d
```

Shouldn't this be

```
a
d
```

if I change the if condition to

```
if(!(secondSample.Any(data=> data.ToString() == s)))
```

I get

```
a
d
```

So my question is am I interpreting the the Any operator in the wrong way? Shouldn't

```
if(secondSample.Any(data=> data.ToString() != s))
```

evaluate to true when values from `secondSample` is not in sample

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use != operator and you expect `a d` as the result then you should use `All` not `Any`:

```
 if(secondSample.All(data=> data.ToString() != s))
           Console.WriteLine(s);
```

**Explanation** `secondSample.Any(data=> data.ToString() != s)` will be true if just one element in `secondSample` was not equal to the given data item (in your `sample` list), so in your case it will be always true and you see all elements is written in the console.

**Better Solution** having two array A and B, if you want those A element which are not in B using LINQ you can can try `Except` and if you are looking for common elements you may try `Intersect`:

```
List<string> A = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
List<string> B= new List<string> { "b", "c" };

var AnotInB = A.Except(B).ToList(); //a, d

var AInB = A.Intersect(B).ToList(); //b, c
```

Answer (score 2):

!= in an Any means ALL are not equal.

So you read if there is Any that is not equal, then you can print. 
 And guess what, you always have at least 1 that is not equal. That's why you get all the answers.

in your other statement you say: the one that is not equal you can print...

any clearer?

Comment: Your explanation was also very good. Concise and to the point. I can only mark one as answer. Otherwise I'd have marked both

Answer (score 1):

Any operator basicaly ask 'is there any elements in collection that answers predicate'. In your case it is exist and so it is correct output.

Answer (score 1):

use exists

```
List<string> sample = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };   

List<string> secondSample = new List<string> { "b", "c" };

foreach (string s in sample)
        {           
          if (!secondSample.Exists(data => data.ToString() == s))            
               Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explain why the Any operator was the wrong choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's All, not Any when you change to !=

```
 if(secondSample.All(data=> (data.ToString() != s)))
```

when you negate an expression the internal or became an and:  the negation of "A or B" becomes "Not A and Not B."